# jquery-ui drag and drop across multiple divs with sort

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to create a jquery drag and drop solution and am a little lost with how I achieve the following.

1. Allow '.todo-task' to be dropped into any of the 4 'backlog, pending, inProgress, completed'  div containers.
2. Use a highlight helper to show where the task will be placed in the container.
3. Be able to drag and drop with in a container to change to order.

my first issue is that I cannot seem to be able to activate the drag items correctly.

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bitcoder/h5rt2qgw/1/) with the code I have so far.  Appreciate any guidance / help

here is my jquery code

```
 $(".task-container").contents().find(".todo-task").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".ui-droppable",
    helper: function (event) {

    },
    iframeFix: true,
    // stop: makeSortable()
    stop: function (event, ui) {
      //  alert('stop');
    }
});   

$(".ui-droppable").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    opacity: .5,
    //dropOnEmpty: true,
    helper: 'original',
    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
     newItem = ui.item;
    },
    receive: function (event, ui) {

    },

}).disableSelection().droppable({
    over: ".ui-droppable",
    activeClass: 'highlight',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");

    }
})
```

Comment: make sure that the draggable elements are not inside other jquery-ui sortable/selectable/resizable etc..containers as this is a known issue with mixing jquery-ui features on same elements. There are solutions but can be very specific depending on the current configuration

Comment: First, in the fiddle, you should include the required library. There's an option on the sidebar of the jsfiddle that allows you to add external resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what else you're trying to achieve in terms of the "disabled" style CSS, but I just forked and monkeyed around with this for a minute:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milesrobinson/gbhw4yj8/1/)

One thing is that I think your jQuery methods are redundant. Why say:

```
$(".task-container").contents().find(".todo-task").draggable( ...etc.
```

When you can just as easily do this:

```
$(".todo-task").draggable( ...etc.
```

So I cleaned a little bit of that up.

The other thing I did was to make the `.task-container` `droppable`.

See the jQuery API: [droppable methods](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/)

This allows you to sort and move between columns, but like I mentioned this fix seems to behave strangely with your CSS class methods.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is working great - its more than enough for me to   tweek further as I develop the solution further...

Comment: Very good solution for drag/drop between multiple DIVs. Thank you very much!